# Google Apps script FTP Upload

Tags: sockets, ftp, google-apps-script, sftp

I read that there is https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/ that can be used by apps.

However, I would need this in a google script so that I can send an email to a gmail adress and then the script taks the attachement from the email and loads it to an ftp server using sftp.

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to do that. It would require a special port and in gas the only ones allowed are for http(s) with urlFetch